# How to connect react-hooks-form and Select from @Mui

Tags: javascript, reactjs, material-ui, frontend, react-hook-form

I am using react-hooks-form to handle forms along with the @Mui library. My problem is how to connect the Select component from @Mui library with react-hooks-form. The task seems simple in theory - I want to fetch the current data from the backend and display it as default values. According to the @Mui documentation, I can achieve this by setting the value and onChange properties, but how can I connect it with react-hooks-form? I would like to use register in order to validate the fields and send them to the backend in a consistent way later on, but if I add register, the Select component stops working.

```
export default function FormSelect() {
  const [gender, setGender] = React.useState('');
  const {
    register,
    formState: { errors },
  } = useForm({});
  
  useEffect(() => {
    axios.get('/get-gender').then((data) => {
      setGender(data.data.gender)
    })
  })

  const handleChange = (event) => {
    setGender(event.target.value);
  };

  return (
      <FormControl fullWidth>
        <InputLabel id="gender">Gender</InputLabel>
        <Select
          labelId="gender"
          id="gender-select"
          value={gender}
          label="Gender"
          onChange={handleChange}
          {...register("gender", {
            required: true
          })}
        >
          <MenuItem value={1}>Male</MenuItem>
          <MenuItem value={2}>Female</MenuItem>
        </Select>
      </FormControl>
  );
}
```

How can I easily connect @Mui with react-hooks-form so that I can set default values of the elements (from the backend) without creating too much mess using useState? Can I completely give up on useState in favor of react-hooks-form methods? Do you know how to solve my problem?

Answer (score 0):

Mui inputs are controlled components while `react-hook-form` works uncontrolled inputs. It is explained in the documentation how you can use `react-hook-form` with controlled inputs. Using `Controller` or `useController`

https://react-hook-form.com/api/usecontroller/controller/